# how to round up a double value to nearest integer in c#

Tags: c#

I am developing a windows forms application.I need to do some conversions and round up the values.I need to round up the double value to nearest integer.For example 1.4 should be 1 and 1.6 should be 2 after applying round up.Please refer my code below.

```
double d = 51386933935386.5;
uint x = (uint)Math.Round(d, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

> After round up I need the value value = 51386933935386.But I am getting some different value.

Comment: What are "different values"?

Comment: you can't store 51386933935386 in an int, use long.

Comment: Any problem on using `Math.Round`? I think due to the last edit the problem can no longer be reproduced and is of no use to future readers on SO.

Comment: just change the Math.Round to case to ulong instead of uint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [max value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) of `UInt` is 4,294,967,295.

You need to keep it a `double` or a `long`

EDIT: Or `ulong` if you want to keep it unsigned

Comment: Or even a `ulong` if he wants to stay with unsigned numbers

Comment: @Scoregraphic thanks, I have edited the answer with your information.

Comment: @David:Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

51386933935386 is longer than `uint` max value. Use next:

```
double d = 51386933935386.5;
long x = (long)Math.Round(d, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not use `Math.Floor(d);' ?

```
double d = 51386933935386.5;
var result = Math.Floor(d);
// result = 51386933935386
```

It returns the number you need.

**Update**

Thanks to @HimBromBeere to point it out you can accomplish your task using the code below.

Use this code

```
double d = 51386933935386.5;
var x = Math.Round(d, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
var result = Convert.ToInt64(x);
```

Comment: Please check the documentation for `Math.Floor` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb(v=vs.110).aspx). As you can see, and I've also tested it, it will return the correct number as requested in the question.

Comment: Yeah @HimBromBeere you are right. I will update the answer. It really depends on his/her requirement to what is best to use in a situation like this.

Comment: Floor will round the number down, it returns the largest integer less than or equal to the specified double-precision floating-point number.  This will mean the 1.4 will return 1, but the 1.6 will return 1 as well, where the question clearly states it should return 2.